# List the current configuration of nginx server

Tags: nginx, configuration

Yesterday I did something quite stupid. I edited a configuration file of my nginx server, throwing away some settings and just after I saved the file I realized I was editing the wrong file.
Now I didn't reload the server, so it is still running with the old configuration.

I would like to know if it's possible to show the current configuration the server is running.

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/361421/dump-nginx-config-from-running-process

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the method linked in [Dump nginx config from running process?](https://serverfault.com/questions/361421/dump-nginx-config-from-running-process)
and you might recover some of it.

After you've done that, take a look at [etckeeper](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/etckeeper.html) [(original)](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) [(howto)](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/keep-configs-under-control-with-etckeeper.html) to prevent this kind of thing from happening again.

It's a fairly straightforward way of keeping /etc stored under version control with Git.

Comment: Thanks, this is one of those situations where *anything* helps. The above answer allowed me to retrieve some of the settings I had in the virtualhost.