# Mechanism to get the current running configuration values in nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration, http, http-proxy

Trying to find an easy and convenient mechanism to get the current configuration values from a running `nginx` instance.

The ideal solution would be a url that I could point to that would print the configuration values that are loaded into the server.

The purpose of this is to verify that the configuration file that I believe to be holding the correct values is indeed being loaded correctly and its values are set.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/361421/dump-nginx-config-from-running-process