# Where does nginx store vhosts config while running

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have accidentally replaced my vhost file in sites-available in nginx. The file contained a lot of 301 redirects, which are still working while the reload command is not run. Does nginx store the files loaded from sites-available while running so that I can copy and restore it or do I have to write the entire file again?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Similar question asked (and answered) at http://serverfault.com/questions/361421/dump-nginx-config-from-running-process

Comment: Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832033/dump-conf-from-running-nginx-process

Answer (score 0):

Run `nginx -T` to get a dump of the current running configuration. This requires nginx 1.9.2 or later.

And for the love of gawd, set up backups.