# how to free up space from deleted open file?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux server out of space](https://serverfault.com/questions/366324/linux-server-out-of-space)

I deleted an open file and the disk usage was not reduced.

Will it free up the space if I deleted the link in /proc/PID/fd/N ? what will happen to the process (in general)?

To be specific:
The server is running Zimbra and the sync.log just gone crazily big occasionally (it's Zimbra's bug)

Answer (score 4):

You have a running process writing to the file. You should have truncated or zeroed the logfile instead of deleting it. See the [detail and explanation of the process here](https://serverfault.com/questions/366324/linux-server-out-of-space/366327#366327), but something like `: > /path/to/sync.log` would work.

At this point, you'll have to restart the Zimbra daemon to realize the newly-freed space.

Obviously, this is treating the symptom, and you'll hopefully have an opportunity to fix this at the Zimbra level.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to delete a file that is being written to is simply cp /dev/null into it

```
cp /dev/null /path/to/file
```

Comment: With usual shells (POSIX sh, bash, ksh, zsh, ...) `: > /path/to/file` or just `> /path/to/file` are simpler and strictly equivalent.